# Ayuda con un Button dentro de un CardView Android Studio

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, cardview

```js
class eventsAdapter(val context: Context, val eventsArray:ArrayList<String>, val timeArrayList: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<eventsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.event_item , p0 , false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return  eventsArray.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        p0.eventText.text = eventsArray[p1]
        p0.eventText.textSize = 18f
        p0.eventText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        addEventDialog()
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val eventText = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTitle)
    }
}
```

He buscado en todos lados y no he encontrado la manera de que presionando el botón de un CardView elimine ese CardView.

Les comento, el CardView está dentro de un RecyclerView, que es un calendario que agrega notas a las fechas del calendario. Lo que quiero es que, presionando ese botón, se elimine la nota.

[image: aca una captura]

El código del CardView es este:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#1976D2">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:id="@+id/textTitle"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <Button
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:id="@+id/borrarnota"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/ic_delete" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="349dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Puedes colocar el código del `RecyclerView` que estas usando y que has intentado para lograr esto

Comment: @DavidVillegas si lo coloco aca, si me puedes ayudar asi aprendo te agradezco mucho!!!
Lo coloco arriba

Comment: @DavidVillegas ya coloque el codigo cuando puedas miralo. gracias!!

Comment: Hola, colocar un boton y eliminar un objeto de la lista son almenos 2 cosas distintas, que es lo que se te complica? agregar el boton? atrapar el onClick? o eliminar el elemento del recycler?

Comment: Hola @ErickSilva gracias por responder!! el boton ya lo pude agregar es la cruz roja que esta al costado a la derecha, entonces lo que quiero hacer es apretando la cruz roja se borre la nota que corresponde a ese boton, es un cardview que esta adentro de un recycler view

Comment: @elfer07 donde estas recuperando el ID del botón? solo veo que recuperas el `TextView`, pero no el botón

Comment: @DavidVillegas claro e intentado recuperarlo y no me sale la accion de eliminar, esa funcion no se como hacerla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien lo que debes hacer para lograr esto es sencillamente, como te pregunte, recuperar el `id` del botón que creaste en tu `CardView`, asumo que es **"borrarnota"**, esto se hará en la clase `ViewHolder`, de esta forma:

```
val boton = view.borrarnota
```

Así obtenemos el id de este botón, ahora en el `onBindViewHolder` nos queda solo invocar el método `onClick` de esta forma:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        /...
        ....
        .../
        p0.button?.setOnClickListener {
            eventsArray.removeAt(p1)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

De esta forma al dar `Click` al botón le estamos diciendo que remueva la posición en la que se encuentra el mismo, por eso le pasamos `p1` que representa la posicion del ítem en el `RecyclerView`.

Comment: David sos muy bueno loco!!! funciono!!! Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: de nada @elfer07 para eso estamos :)

Comment: David vos sabes que me lo borra pero cuando vuelvo sigue estando ahi, como que no lo borra de la base de datos!!!

Comment: Para eso tienes que implementar otra forma de guardado y llenado de `RecyclerView`, de esa forma borras el ítem, pero como estas llenando el contenido seguro en tu `MainActivity` cada vez que entres en el `OnCreate` de tu actividad te volverá a crear los `items`, Puedes usar `SharedPreferences` o `SQLite`, para guardar, mostrar en el `RecyclerView`, y cuando realices el borrado, creas funciones para borrar esos ítems del almacenamiento que decidas usar.

Comment: Si estoy usando un sqliteDB para guardar esa nota,
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS calendar (id INTEGER primary key , event TEXT , day INTEGER , month INTEGER , year INTEGER , time TEXT)")
    }
y lo guarda en el dia del mes y del año
no existe una funcion para que borre ese agregado a la db?

Comment: Me parece que tendrías que crear una instrucción de eliminar el campo que deseas, dependiendo de como lo hagas puedes llamarla desde allí mismo de ese onClick, pero por eso me refiero al depende de como lo hagas, si necesitas hacerlo en tu actividad para mas comodidad o mejor manejo, debes implementar interfaces para manejar todo el proceso de eliminado desde la actividad y no desde el adaptador.

Comment: decis que hacerlo desde el adaptador dentro del onClick es mas complicado?

Comment: No hay manera de eliminar ese campo agregado a la db desde ese mismo boton? 
Porque hago el ingreso de las notas con esta funcion
val dbConnection = sqliteDB(context)
                dbConnection.insertIntoDB(eventTitle.text.toString(), eventDate.dayOfMonth,eventDate.month + 1, eventDate.year)

Comment: No es que sea mas complicado, es lo mismo solo que se ejecutara desde diferentes lugares por decirlo de alguna forma, es cuestión de como quieras el orden de tu código, si las acciones de eliminar las quieres manejar desde el adaptador o desde la actividad, es cuestión de preferencias, si lo haces desde el adaptador debes crear métodos que pueda ser llamados desde allí para ejecutar esa acción, si lo haces desde la actividad, debes pasar la posición del ítem a eliminar a la actividad usando interfaces.

Comment: me convence mas la forma desde el adaptador asi no se me hace tanto lio soy muy nuevo en esto me parece que seria lo mejor desde el adaptador, cuales serian las acciones de eliminar y cuales serian los metodos, tenes algun ejemplo para hacerlo?